# is z3 ignoring some of my restrictions?

Tags: z3, smt, sat-solvers

stackoverflow-ers(?),

I'm playing with z3, and I'm trying to solve the following restrictions:

```
(declare-const A (_ BitVec 32))
(declare-const B (_ BitVec 32))
(declare-const C (_ BitVec 32))
(declare-const D (_ BitVec 32))
(declare-const E (_ BitVec 32))
(declare-const F (_ BitVec 32))

(assert (<= A #xFFFFFFFF))
(assert (<= B #xFFFFFFFF))
(assert (<= C #xFFFFFFFF))


(assert (> A #x00000000))

;(Commented) Restriction #1 (assert (> B #x00000000))
(assert (> C #x00000000))

(assert (= D (bvand (bvmul (bvmul A B) #x00000008) #xFFFFFFFF) ))
(assert (<= D #xFFFFFFFF))

(assert (= E (bvand (bvmul (bvmul A C) #x00000008) #xFFFFFFFF)))
(assert (<= D E))

(assert (= F (bvand (bvmul A #x00000008) #xFFFFFFFF)))    

;(Uncommented) Restriction #2
(assert (> (bvand (bvmul F B) #xFFFFFFFF) D))

(assert (< (bvand (bvmul A B) #xFFFFFFFF) #x7FFFFFFF))
(assert (< (bvand (bvmul A C) #xFFFFFFFF) #x7FFFFFFF))


(assert (< D #x01000000))

(check-sat)

(get-value(A))
(get-value(B))
(get-value(C))
(get-value(D))
(get-value(F))
```

I've got some troubles with these constraints:
a) The first problem is that z3 is ignoring "Restriction #2"

```
(assert (> (bvand (bvmul F B) #xFFFFFFFF) D))
```

,the values I get are the followings:

```
A: #x000070e0
B: #x0000000a
C: #x00000014
D: #x00234600
F: #x00038700
```

and F*B = D in spite of the restriction.

b) if I uncomment "Restriction #1"

```
(assert (> B #x00000000))
```

I'm getting the following result:

```
A: #x0000a000
B: #x00000007
C: #x00000000
```

is it a chair - keyboard interface bug? what am I doing wrong?

[Run this on Z3 online.](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/Mcdp)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For comparing bit-vectors, you should always use the corresponding signed/unsigned variants: `bvult`, `bvugt`, `bvule`, `bvuge` for unsigned, and `bvslt`, `bvsgt`, `bvsle`, `bvsge` for signed. The use of `<`, `>` etc. is not valid. So, your "restrictions" are actually currently being simply ignored. If I run your benchmark on the command line, I get the following output:

```
(error "line 8 column 24: Sort mismatch at argument #1 for function (declare-fun <= (Int Int) Bool) supplied sort is (_ BitVec 32)")
(error "line 9 column 24: Sort mismatch at argument #1 for function (declare-fun <= (Int Int) Bool) supplied sort is (_ BitVec 32)")
(error "line 10 column 24: Sort mismatch at argument #1 for function (declare-fun <= (Int Int) Bool) supplied sort is (_ BitVec 32)")
(error "line 13 column 23: Sort mismatch at argument #1 for function (declare-fun > (Int Int) Bool) supplied sort is (_ BitVec 32)")
(error "line 16 column 24: Sort mismatch at argument #1 for function (declare-fun > (Int Int) Bool) supplied sort is (_ BitVec 32)")
(error "line 19 column 24: Sort mismatch at argument #1 for function (declare-fun <= (Int Int) Bool) supplied sort is (_ BitVec 32)")
(error "line 22 column 15: Sort mismatch at argument #1 for function (declare-fun <= (Int Int) Bool) supplied sort is (_ BitVec 32)")
(error "line 27 column 44: Sort mismatch at argument #1 for function (declare-fun > (Int Int) Bool) supplied sort is (_ BitVec 32)")
(error "line 29 column 52: Sort mismatch at argument #1 for function (declare-fun < (Int Int) Bool) supplied sort is (_ BitVec 32)")
(error "line 30 column 52: Sort mismatch at argument #1 for function (declare-fun < (Int Int) Bool) supplied sort is (_ BitVec 32)")
(error "line 33 column 23: Sort mismatch at argument #1 for function (declare-fun < (Int Int) Bool) supplied sort is (_ BitVec 32)")
sat
((A #x00000000))
((B #x00000000))
((C #x00000000))
((D #x00000000))
((F #x00000000))
```

I'm not sure why the "online" solver isn't similarly complaining.

Comment: thanks for your replay. The online z3 solver is running like z3.exe /smt2. In that case, these error doesn't appear. Anyway I will try replace it

Comment: I't works for me, I've detected an error in the constrains, I'll to fix it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "it works for me." The use of `<`, `>` etc. for bit-vectors is just not correct. But perhaps you meant something else.

Comment: I mean that replacing '<' for 'bvult', and all the operators for the proper operators works fine for me. Also, analising the contrains I found an error in 2 oposite contrains, being as a result unsat. thx.